# Can Google compute engine addInstance fail due to no resources available?

Tags: google-compute-engine

If I am within my quota am I guaranteed to be able to have my instance created (assumimg all other inputs are valid) - trying to determine if my quota equates to reserved capacity that I can count on to be available if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine is engineered for scale, and a fundamental design goal is enabling all users to scale their workloads up (and down) on demand.

However, quotas are not private reservations and [`instances.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert) can fail in rare cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - is there a way to "guarantee/reserve" capacity in GCE at this time ?